# where not in subquery - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The inner query in the following SQL statement is to normalize part of the database (code1, code2, code3, etc.) With the outer query I want to select the codes that aren't in the lookup table (tblicd)

```
select primarycode from 
(
select id, primarycode from myTable
union
select id, secondarycode from myTable
union 
select id, tertiarycode from myTable) as t
order by id
where primarycode not in tblicd.icd_id
```

The query above doesn't run, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.  The error I get is `the multi-part identifier tblicd.icd_id could not be bound`

Comment: So what's the question? Does your code work? If not, what's the problem?

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Comment: the query doesn't run.  I'm curious to see what I'm missing

Comment: what is the error message tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where primarycode not in tblicd.icd_id
```

might be

```
where primarycode not in (SELECT icd_id FROM tblicd )
```

Comment: thanks, this works.  forgot that I had to select something in the where field not in part.

Answer (score 6):

One problem is your `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clauses are reversed. The `ORDER BY` clause must come after the `WHERE` clause.

Your `WHERE` clause is also incorrect. It should be like this:

```
WHERE primarycode NOT IN (SELECT icd_id FROM tblicd)
ORDER BY id
```